# Textfields in a Row Not Aligned on Validation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottom sheet that displays a set of text fields and on there is a row with two textfields. These two textfields have validation and when one field meets the validation and the other doesn't, the textfields in this row get misaligned.

[image]

As you can see, 'Expires End' is not aligned with 'CVV' when there is a validation message showing. How can I make sure that the aligns when there is a validation message.

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 5):

Just Wrap your Row With IntrinsicHeight and set alignment of Row.

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      TextField(),
      TextField()
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the settings in the `decoration` argument of `TextField`:
you can set the error text height as below in order to avoid the widget rearrangement on failed validation:

```
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
  )
```

This will keep the widget aligned, but then you have to put a `Text` widget somewhere, because this will mess up the layout if you return a `String` from your validator to show an error.

Here's an more complete example: since this was a password field of a login field, I didn't need to show an error to let the user understand that something was wrong, and the red underline that appeared was enough to let the user understand what went wrong

```
//...at some point in your form
TextFormField(
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Password',
    errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
  ),
  controller: pwdTec,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty || value.length < 8) {
      return ""; //this will just underline the field in red
    }
    return null;
  },
  onFieldSubmitted: (_) => _formSubmit(),
),
Text(_errorMessage), //_errorMessage is a field of a StatefulWidget, that gets update by _formSubmit() with a setState() in case of errors that require an explanation

//...rest of the form
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a helper text that is empty
Ex :-
helperText: ""

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34445510)

Answer (score 0):

use the validator property and the decoration property in TextFormField widget to show the error message

```
Form(
    key: formkey,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        TextFormField(
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9]')),
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(25),
            ],
            controller: controller,
            obscureText: isPassword,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            validator: validateEmail,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                filled: true))
      ],
    ),
  ),
```